# How can I modify the "Paid" booking status label in WooCommerce Bookings

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-bookings

Using WooCommerce Bookings - I am trying to modify the booking status label which appears on customer-facing front-end views and in customer emails. When a reservation is booked, in the booking summary it displays a status label of "Paid", but since I am using this to book free reservations I don't want it to say "Paid" anywhere because that will confuse customers. I'm trying to get it to say "Booked" instead. Literally all I care about is the text that appears, I'm not trying to modify any status in the actual booking or order.

I would hide the element with CSS, but that same html element is used to display a "Cancelled" label if the customer cancel the booking, and I don't want that hidden. Also hiding it in CSS would not prevent "Paid" from appearing in the customer booking confirmation emails.

In /order/booking-display.php I located this code where the status is being displayed:

```
echo esc_html( wc_bookings_get_status_label( $booking->get_status() ) );
```

I assume this is relevant, but I'm a designer & marketer, not a developer, so this is over my head. I have been searching everywhere for a way to do this, but can't figure this out. Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

WooCommerce normally doesn't allow you to change the core order statuses which are Paid, Cancelled, On Hold. However, if you are looking for a paid solution, there's an extension provided by WooCommerce which allows you to do so. You may wanna check this out:
https://woocommerce.com/products/woocommerce-order-status-manager/

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks you for the insight. I did come across that plugin but it wasn't clear that it would actually solve my problem. Regardless, right after I posted this question I realized... why don't I just use conditional statements to check the booking status and display different markup depending on the status? So I did that and it worked like a charm. Should've been obvious to me but this is what happens when you've been working 14 hours and 9 days straight!  But, I appreciate the help, nonetheless!

Answer (score 0):

Right after I posted this question I realized... why don't I just use conditional statements to check the booking status and display different markup depending on the status? So I did that and it worked like a charm. I'll update this answer with the code in the morning.